# How to add two solutions

Tags: python

So this code works, but I want it to print two solutions off a text-file. The problem includes trying to print out two lines in a text file, when keywords are used with `if 'word' == something then print`, I want to print two lines. Any help would be appreciated. I have tried various different things.

```
problem = False

while problem == False:

    foo = open("solutions.txt","r")

    print("What is wrong with your device?")

    issue=input()

    if (('wet' in issue) or ('water' in issue)):
        solutions = foo.readlines()
        print(solutions[0])
        problem = True

    if (('cracked' in issue) or ('dropped' in issue)):
        solutions = foo.readlines()
        print(solutions[1])
        problem = True
```

Comment: Please post the code as text!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for. Can you give a specific example?  Do you want to print solutions[3] twice or print solutions[3] and something else for when the issue is 'smashed'? for instance?

Comment: Like if I say cracked and dropped for instance i need it to print out two solutions for both of them because right now it only prints out one and i have no idea how to even start.

Answer (score 0):

If the solutions are always fixed, you should move the file opening and reading outside the loop. The match between keywords and solution index can be done with a dictionary.

```
problem = False

foo = open("solutions.txt","r")
solutions = foo.readlines()

Problemlistdict = {'wet':0, 'water':0, 'dropped':1, 'sim card':2} #etc..etc

while problem == False:

    print("What is wrong with your device?")

    issue=input()

    sol = set()

    for k in Problemlistdict.keys():
        if k in issue:
            sol.add(Problemlistdict[k])
```

The result will be a set sol containing the index for the all the relevant solution lines.

Answer (score 0):

Add a stop-index to your  line-selection:

`solutions[0:1]` will return the first two lines of the file, not only the first line.

Or for two lines not following immediately each other, do:

`solutions[2] + solutions[7]`

See "[Accessing lists](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm#accessing)" from F. Lundbergh as an arbitrary example of endless Python-docs explaining this.

Additionally you may change every following `if` after the first one to `elif` and add an `else`, for the case that none of your chosen issues is found in the user's input.

And it is recommended to use `with` instead for `open`, to make sure the file closes properly. If you use Python < 2.7 and you have to use `open`, don't forget to `close` again.